# When $\operatorname{Lie}(\ker(\phi))=\ker(d\phi_e)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, derivations

Let $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be a morphism of (linear or not?) algebraic groups. What are, in general, the conditions to assure
$$\operatorname{Lie}(\ker(\phi))=\ker(d\phi_e)\text{?}$$

Comment: This is always true if by algebraic group you mean group scheme of finite type over a field. (It is obvious in that setting that Lie is left exact,)

Comment: So in that case, it always true with no condition on $\phi$?

Comment: @FilippoSneakerhead Are you specifically interested in characteristic $p>0$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is separable, then $\text{Lie}(\text{ker}(\phi))=\text{ker}(d\phi_e)$. This is essentially Exercise 12.1 in Humphreys's *Linear Algebraic Groups*.

Comment: Inserting on behalf of [@BCnrd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3927/bcnrd) the obligatory warning that, if you think you need to worry about separability, you're probably using the wrong notion of 'kernel'.

Comment: For example, the scheme-theoretic kernel of $\phi : \operatorname{SL}_p \to \operatorname{PGL}_p$ in characteristic $p$ is the subgroup scheme $\mu_p$ of $p$th roots of unity.  This, not the reduced group scheme underlying it (which is the trivial group scheme), is the appropriate notion of 'kernel' here.  (For example, it satisfies the isomorphism theorem $\operatorname{SL}_p/\mu_p \cong \operatorname{PGL}_p$.)

Comment: This is probably what the comments by [@anon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333677/when-operatornamelie-ker-phi-kerd-phi-e#comment833381_333677) and [@FrancoisZiegler](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333677/when-operatornamelie-ker-phi-kerd-phi-e#comment834046_333677) on your original question were indicating.